# Installing OCI8 on mac XAMPP PHP 7.4.20 fails with Failed to Detect PHP version

Tags: php, macos, apache, oci8

I'm trying to install oci8 on XAMPP php 7.4.20 which is on Mac OS monterey but i keep getting this error "configure: error: failed to detect PHP version, please report"

i have tried setting up using the below process

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/installing-xampp-on-macos-for-php-and-oracle-database

Below is my error log

Some things i have tried is install XAMPP with php 8.1.6 and when i try to install i get the same error.

I installed a different extention using pecl and it was successful but somehow the oci8 extenstion keeps failing

I have configured my php in the .zshrc and am able to get the correct php path when i run
`which php`
and i also get the correct php version when i run `php --version` as show in the last command on the error log

What could be the issue.

```
sudo pecl install oci8-2.2.0
Password:
downloading oci8-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.2.0.tgz (196,449 bytes)
.........................................done: 196,449 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
configure.ac:18: warning: $as_echo is obsolete; use AS_ECHO(["message"]) instead
build/php.m4:2162: PHP_CONFIG_NICE is expanded from...
configure.ac:18: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2800: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2726: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:697: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:704: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2264: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2277: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:718: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2800: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2726: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2921: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:697: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:704: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2264: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2277: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:718: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2800: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2726: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2800: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2726: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2800: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2726: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not exist
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: output file \`$ofile' does not look like a libtool script
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: using \`LTCC=$LTCC', extracted from \`$ofile'
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: tag name \"$tagname\" already exists
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:262: AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:3808: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2808: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:3808: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2808: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: back quotes and double quotes must not be escaped in: $as_me: WARNING: \`$CC' does not support \`-c -o', so \`make -j' may be unsafe
build/libtool.m4:1205: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:3808: _LT_AC_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2808: AC_LIBTOOL_LANG_CXX_CONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1997: _LT_AC_TAGCONFIG is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:209: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:65: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:47: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] : instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/oracle/instantclient_19_8
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootrfgnIr/oci8-2.2.0
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config --with-oci8=instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamamppfiles/lib/oracle/instantclient_19_8
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... Unknown option: n
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
    -m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
    -f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
    -b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
    -t <timeout>  Set timeout value
    -i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
    -c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
    -a            Use text mode for content I/O
    -p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
    -P            don't load proxy settings from environment
    -H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

    -u            Display method and URL before any response
    -U            Display request headers (implies -u)
    -s            Display response status code
    -S            Display response status chain
    -e            Display response headers
    -d            Do not display content
    -o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

    -v            Show program version
    -h            Print this message

    -x            Extra debugging output
configure: error: failed to detect PHP version, please report
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/oci8/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config --with-oci8=instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamamppfiles/lib/oracle/instantclient_19_8' failed
mac@macs-MacBook-Pro instantclient-basiclite-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru % php --version
PHP 7.4.20 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2021 04:37:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
mac@macs-MacBook-Pro instantclient-basiclite-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru % php --version
```

Comment: `checking PHP version... Unknown option: n` -- This means that the installation script is issuing a `php --version -n`  or some variation thereof -- This flag in Linux version of PHP tells the command to skip the INI file ..  I am assuming you are using a Linux install on a Mac .. Or don't have a version of PHP that will accept the `-n` Flag on mac.

Comment: @Zak am using mac os the last command on the error log am the one who run the php --version. how can i force the configure script to use that

Comment: The `-n` option is _not_ being issued to the `php` command, it's being issued to the `head` command. From the help that gets dumped, it looks like you have a non-standard `head` command in your path -- something that is trying to make an HTTP request. The `head` command that is actually expected here should be a text utility to print the first few lines of a file.